# shopizer can't resolve lanuage when lang is "_all"

Tags: spring-boot, shopizer

I'm working in the shopizer 3.x
It is always return error when I got to cartegory detail (/category/{friendlyUrl}) or product detail (/private/product/{id}).

It can't resolve when language is null.
When debuging, lang is "_all", and also saw the following comment.
"//if language is null then underlying facade must load all languages"

This ploblem is not occured before feb. 2023.
After mar. 2023, many commits was proceeded.
I can't understand what modified or added code is affected it.

How can I fix it?
I try to fix it for 3 days, but still i can't fix it.

Please help me.

I tested shopizer using shopizer-admin (angular 2+ frontend)
When I want to go category details or product details, Always null point exception because language is null.